# Returning a variable sized array of doubles from C++ to C# - a simpler way?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pinvoke

I have the following C++ method :

__declspec(dllexport)  void __stdcall getDoubles(int *count, double **values);
the method allocates and fills an array of double and sets *count to the size of the array.

The only way i managed to get this to work via pinvoke is :

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("xx.dll")]
 public static extern void getDoubles(ref int count, ref System.IntPtr values);
```

and usage is :

```
int count = 0;
IntPtr doubles = new IntPtr();
Nappy.getDoubles(ref count, ref doubles);
double[] dvs = new double[count];
for(int i = 0;i < count;++{
    dvs[i] = (double)Marshal.PtrToStructure(doubles, typeof(System.Double));
    doubles = new IntPtr(doubles.ToInt64()+Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(System.Double)));
}
```

the values end up in the dvs array.
Is there a better way ti do this not invloving pointer arithmetic in a managed language...

Comment: The description is incomplete - HOW does it allocate the memory, and how is it returned to that allocator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use

```
Marshal.Copy( source, destination, 0, size );
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the unmanaged method signature so it reads like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall getDoubles(SAFEARRAY *array);
```

Then you should be able to use the following managed version of the function:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("xx.dll")]
public static extern void getDoubles(
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VT_R8)]
              double[] array
);
```

Of course that you'll also have to rewrite your unmanaged code to work with SAFEARRAYs.
More about this topic [can be found at MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx)

One question though, I recall working with ZLib in C# which is able, without any wrapper, to work with byte[] while the unmanaged counterpart is BYTE*, have you tried working directly with double* / double[] ?

Comment: I have tried using double []  or ref double directly but that only work for a single level of indirection. there is support for marshalling an array of doubles if you know the size on the managed side.