# How to pass C# array to C++ and return it back to C# with additional items?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, marshalling

I have a C# project which is using a C++ dll. (in visual studio 2010)
I have to pass a array of int  from C# code to C++ function and C++ function will add few elements in array, when control comes back to C# code, C# code will also add elements in same array. 
 Initially i declared a array(of size 10000) in C# code and C++ code is able to add elements (because it was just an array of int, memory allocation is same), but the problems is i have got run time error due to accessing out side of array.

I can increase size to 100000 but again i don't know how much elements C++ code will add( even it can be just 1 element).

So is there a common data structure (dynamic array) exist for both or other way to do? I am using Visual studio 2010.

Something like this i want to do. 
PS: not compiled code, and here i used char array instead of int array.

C# code

```
[DllImport("example1.dll")]
private static extern int fnCPP (StringBuilder a,int size)
...

private void fnCSHARP(){
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(10000);
    int size=0;
    size = fnCPP (buff,size);
    int x = someCSHARP_fu();
    for ( int i=size; i < x+size; i++) buff[i]='x';// possibility of run time error
}
```

C++ code

```
int fnCPP (char *a,int size){
  int x = someOtherCpp_Function();
  for( int i=size; i < x+size ; i++) a[ i ] = 'x'; //possibility of run time error 
  return size+x;
}
```

Comment: Can you use C++/CLI?Can you use C++/CLI?

Comment: You can't "add" items to an array.  Arrays are fixed in size.  Use a different data structure or change how you interface between the two.

Comment: @Jeff that was not exactly "add", i have added code to clear from my side

Answer (score 8):

There's a good MSDN article about passing arrays between managed and unmanaged code [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx). The question is, why would you need to pass the array from C# to C++ in the first place? Why can't you do the allocation on the C++ side (in your fnCPP method), and return a pointer to the C# code, and than just use `Marshal.Copy( source, destination, 0, size )` as in [yet another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442699/retruning-a-variable-sized-array-of-doubles-from-c-to-c-a-simpler-way)? Than in your fnCSHARP method you could copy the contents of the array to some varaiable length data structure (e.g. List).

Comment: If you allocate memory in C++ and return it to C#, you need to later pass the pointer back to C++ to free the memory.  The .NET garbage collector can't help you here.