# Pass array from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to pass an array from C# to a C++ DLL and then print it from C++.

The C# code is the following:

```
[DllImport("DLL1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void GMSH_PassVector([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray,SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_I4)] int[] curveTag);

int[] curveTagArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
GMSH_PassVector(curveTagArray);
```

The C++ header file code is the following:

```
extern "C" GMSH_API  void GMSH_PassVector(std::vector<int> *curveTags);
```

The C++ cpp file code is the following to display the first element of the array:

```
void GMSH_PassVector(std::vector<int> *curveTags)
{
    printf("Hello %d \n", curveTags[0]);
}
```

Seems that I'm doing something wrong, a value is displayed but it is the wrong one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass C# array to C++ and return it back to C# with additional items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624561/how-to-pass-c-sharp-array-to-c-and-return-it-back-to-c-sharp-with-additional-i)

Comment: I don't think the marshal mechanism is able to translate a `int[]` to a `std::vector`. It's better to use language base types. Change the C++ function as `void GMSH_PassVector(int * arr, int size)` and in C# you have to instantiate a `IntPtr` to hold the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the marshal mechanism is able to translate a int[] to a std::vector. It's better to use language base types. Change the C++ function as

`void GMSH_PassVector(int * arr, int size)`

and in C# you have to instantiate a
IntPtr to hold the address of the first element of the array.

```
int bufferSize = 4;
int[] buffer = new int[bufferSize];

buffer[0] = 1;
buffer[1] = 2;
buffer[2] = 3;
buffer[3] = 4;

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(buffer[0]) * buffer.Length;
IntPtr bufferPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, bufferPtr, size);

GMSH_PassVector(bufferPtr, size);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferPtr);
```