# Passing A Byte[] Segment From C# To C++ DLL Without Creating a Copy

Tags: c#

I need to slice a `byte[]` and pass the sliced section to a C# DLL for processing. I am avoiding `Array.Copy`, because I am trying not to copy anything to hinder performance. I have been made aware of the `ArraySegment` class as well as `Span` and `Memory`. The confusion I am having is how to actually pass these to the DLL, as I am passing an `UnmanagedType.LPArray` like so:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate int ProcessVideoFrame_t([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] bytes, uint len);
```

Is there any way to get an underlying byte[] from these classes, or somehow pass the segment without making a copy?

My current code is:

````
byte[] bytes = new byte[packet.Payload.Length - headerSize];
Array.Copy(packet.Payload, headerSize, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

helper.ProcessVideoFrame(CookieHelperDictionary[packet.Header.Cookie], bytes, (uint)bytes.Length);```
````

Comment: Look ath this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625269/421195

Comment: @paulsm4 His suggestion was allocating the buffer on the C++ side and passing a pointer back to C# to copy. I am trying to avoid the copy altogether if possible. Unless I'm misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: Interop/PInvoke (and other .Net variants) definitely allows you to pass just a *POINTER* by value, such that the *BYTE DATA* needn't be copied (duplicated).  Of course, *somebody* needs to allocate the array.  If you choose to allocate on the C++ side ... then you must remember to have C++ free it as well.  Look more carefully at the example.  See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/ (several articles)

Comment: @paulsm4 Check my answer I just posted below. I was able to come up with this idea earlier, and it doesn't require any further allocations or copies. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* p = &packet.Payload[headerSize])
    {
        helper.ProcessVideoFrame(CookieHelperDictionary[packet.Header.Cookie], (IntPtr)p, (uint)(packet.Payload.Length - headerSize));
    }
}
```

I also changed the function definition to this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate int ProcessVideoFrame_t(IntPtr rdh, IntPtr buffer, uint len);
```